# Wordpress Permalink structure Change not working for some posts

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have my blog in wordpress 3.4.1, and buddypress 1.5.6.
Earlier, I was using the permalinks as the %postname%
then later on for the inclusion in Google news I updated my blog permalink structure to /%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ and applied redirection of all the old posts backlinks to the new one manually by the help of redirection plugin of Wordpress.
Now I changed my blog structure to change to /%category%/%postname%/ and applied the proper redirection as indicated by the redirection tool provided by you in htaccess.  Its also working fine for the few posts but for the older posts its still taking the old permalink Structure.
I assumed that It may be conflicting because of the redirection plugin applied. but it is not really so as I have tried after deleting the plugin as well.

The redirection working for few and not for other is really strange to me.

If anyone could help. It will be really great.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: Post your htaccess file code.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myblog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myblog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some permalink transients haven't been cleared yet.. 
Try running this sql:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_%');
```